# Is it possible to add minus button to numeric keypad?

Tags: swift, keyboard

I want to add a minus button to left-bottom corner in numeric keypad. Is it possible to add minus button?

Comment: i think you want smth like [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28101460/how-to-add-a-minus-sign-to-the-decimalpad-ios-keyboard)

Comment: where is KeyboardViewController.swift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible to modify the system keyboards. The best you could do is include a bar at the top of the keyboard. See the documentation on [Custom Views for Data Input](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html).